# java 7 uuid bug?

Tags: java, scala, uuid

I believe I may have found a UUID multi-threading bug in Oracle Java7  Update 5 and I was wondering if anyone could confirm with an independent example. Basically what happens is if I call UUID.Random() concurrently (I'm using 64 threads), I get a collision quickly most of the time).

However, If the UUID generator is warmed up by running a test beforehand that just tosses a bunch of UUIDs it seems to work fine. Here's a gist in scala:

https://gist.github.com/3318973

Important to note that I'm inserting into a mutable Set that I'm synchronizing from 64 different threads. The main thread blocks waiting for the workers to finish and then checks that the set size is what it should be. Collisions are printed as they occur.

thanks!
Adam

Comment: let's see...option a: there is a bug in java7. option b: some random guy on the internet failed to write thread safe code

Comment: option c: a snide comment becomes ironically hilarious when option a: turns out to be true.

Comment: Can StackOverflow badge this question as "the ONE time there really WAS a problem with the GUID generator"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be this:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7071826

It's fixed in 7u6, which should be out soon.

Comment: Hmm, not much description there, but 'race condition' does seem to imply a problem with multiple threads. I'm going to write a java example to eliminate scala/scalatest as the possibility.

Comment: You could also try a preview build of 7u6 from http://jdk7.java.net/archive/7u6-b23.html

Comment: Although that bug report doesn't have any details, there definitely was a bug that would result in duplicate UUIDs. (I helped review the fix.) The 7u6 build should have the fix.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. I was pulling my hair out over this one. I'll just synchronize my UUID generation and suffer the performance loss until the offical 7u6 comes out. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick check with Java 1.7.0_05 (no scala or scalatest involved) and could not reproduce any UUID collisions whatsoever. My basic setup is the same, with 128 threads throwing 10000 uids at a synchronized set each. This is very likely an issue with your testcode, which i can't doublecheck on this machine atm.

Comment: I wrote a quick Java example and I'm not getting a collision either (https://gist.github.com/3323860). I guess it's time to carefully start inspecting the scala.

Comment: Btw, I got it to happen in java. I'm using ConcurrentSkipListSet (https://gist.github.com/3324954. Should also mention that I have a quad-core laptop with hyperthreading.